# Are there any easy known ways to play DnD 5e without other real people?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, solo

I love DnD 5e and do play it with my friends a lot, but of course I am not always right next to 3 or more other friends who happen to know how to play DnD (and if I am, I do not always have the time).

So I was wondering how I could play it without other people nearby.

For example, are there any online DnD simulators, giving me a virtual party, DM, and NPCs?  I have seen some material online describing in great detail how to create a setting, NPCs, etc. However, learning all of this would take way too much time, and I am looking for something simpler.

Alternatively, are there any servers allowing characters to play together without planning in advance? (I.E. you just come and hook up with a couple other people with the same purpose and play a meaningful session. Preferably without sound/voice.) Planning to play with friends over the internet is equivalent to meeting up in real life, so I am looking for something that will allow me to just open an application/website and start playing (with random people) in under 15 minutes.

Lastly, are there any books that set up an adventure and narrate what happens? (Example below, but I am looking for one specifically for DnD.)

[image: Here is an example of what I mean by the book.]

If any of what you know requires me to play more than 1 character at a time, I am fine with that.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. You *could* always just play *Car Wars* instead. I kid! I kid! (Although there *is* [a question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18612) about doing just that on a sister site.) I hope you receive the answer you seek. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Incidentally it looks like someone's asked about this before, so there's some answers ready & waiting.

Comment: @doppelgreener I don't think it is really a duplicate. The question you've linked is about being a player and a DM in the same time, and this question asks for kind of "DnD simulator", a DM replacement.

Comment: @enkryptor That'd make this a tool recommendation, and an unbounded undifferentiated list of tools at that, either of which would get this question closed. Per [our current policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5883/1204), instead of asking for "recommend me a tool that does X" we should ask "how can I do X?" (where the answer might involve a tool or might not) which seems to be exactly what the dupe target is doing.

Comment: @doppelgreener to me, bob didn't ask for recommendation, he asked if such tools even existed for D&D — "are there any books that set up an adventure and narrate what happens". The linked question doesn't address that.

Comment: @enkryptor That pretty much just winds up in the same place.

Comment: What I meant is that I am looking for a tool to do this, and as soon as I get one valid/helpful answer, I will accept it and request to close this thread. The question that this is a "duplicate" has no answers that don't require me to DM for myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, bob, this site doesn't really handle those kinds of questions well, as per doppelgreener's larger comment above. Take a look at the [tour] as per Hey I Can Chan's comment, as well as the reading the linked meta-question in doppelgreener's comment, which should hopefully put some more context to all this...

Comment: I agree with @enkryptor that this question is not really a duplicate. But since is was declared so and got closed, I posted an answer under the question it has been directed to: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77924/is-it-possible-to-play-dd-5e-solo/130900#130900